# Doubly-linked list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

It turned out to be an error as a time limit was exceeded,
but I've already raised the StopIteration...

I think I did something wrong for my iteration part, but it's really hard to find the error. The test output keeps running and even printed out the None value. How does it happen?

```
class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.__current = head.get_next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__current == None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self.__current.get_data()
            self.__current = self.__current.get_next()
            return item
```

These were the inputs I used to run the program:

```
my_list = LinkedListDLL()
my_list.add_to_head(1)
print("Contents:", end=" ")
for node in my_list:
    print(node, end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: How is your node class defined?

Comment: Please update your question with the class definition of your `NodeDLL` class so it can be properly indented.

Comment: yes i've been uploaded more detailed for my code

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code as text like you did for `LinkedListIterator`, instead of posting it as a picture, so we can easily run it and try it out ourselves?

Comment: oops sorry for that... it's my first time to use this website

Comment: No problem. Can you also provide the input you use, which causes the said error?

Comment: sure, will do !

Answer (score 1):

This code is meant to stop iteration when it reaches the head of the list.

```
    if self.__current == None:
        raise StopIteration
```

However, you represent the head with a `NodeDLL` object which is different from `None`.

You could keep a reference to the head and check against that instead:

```
class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self._head = head
        self._current = head.get_next()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._current is self._head:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item = self._current.get_data()
            self._current = self._current.get_next()
            return item
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to implement is the API of a `MutableSequence` with the implementation of a doubly-linked-list.

To do that in Python, you should rely on `collections.abc` which can guide you through the process of implementing all required methods.

By example, a linked-list is actually a class inheriting from `MutableSequence`.

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class LinkedList(MutableSequence):
    pass

ll = LinkedList()
```

On instantiation of a class which has some abstract methods not yet written, you will get a `TypeError` which will guide you through which methods need to be implemented.

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class LinkedList with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __len__, __setitem__, insert
```

In particular, note that a `list` or a linked-list is not an *iterator*, it is an *iterable*. What this means is the `__iter__` method should not return `self` and rely on `__next__`, it should instead return a brand new iterator on the content of the linked-list.

In other words, you can iterate only once through an *iterator* and multiple times through and *iterable*.

### Full implementation

It turns out I have a full implementation of a doubly-linked-list implemented that way. You can have a look.

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class LinkedList(MutableSequence):
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, value, _next=None, _last=None):
            self.value, self._next, self._last = value, _next, _last

        def __str__(self):
            return f'Node({self.value})'

    def __init__(self, iterable=()):
        self.start = None
        self.last = None

        empty = object()
        iterable = iter(iterable)
        first = next(iterable, empty)

        if first is empty:
            return

        current = self._Node(first)
        self.start, self.last = current, current

        for value in iterable:
            new_node = self._Node(value, _last=self.last)
            self.last._next = new_node
            self.last = new_node


    def __len__(self):
        if self.start is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def __iter_nodes(self):
        current = self.start

        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current._next

    def __reversed_iter_nodes(self):
        current = self.last

        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current._last

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.__iter_nodes():
            yield node.value

    def __reversed__(self):
        for node in self.__reversed_iter_nodes():
            yield node.value

    def __get_node(self, index):
        if index >= 0:
            for item in self.__iter_nodes():
                if index == 0:
                    return item
                index -= 1
        else:
            for item in self.__reversed_iter_nodes():
                if index == 0:
                    return item
                index += 1
        raise IndexError

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index >= 0:
            for item in self:
                if index == 0:
                    return item.value
                index -= 1
        else:
            for item in reversed(self):
                if index == 0:
                    return item.value
                index += 1
        raise IndexError

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self[key].value = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        node = self[key]
        if node._last:
            node._last._next = node._next
        if node._next:
            node._next._last = node._last

    def insert(self, index, value):
        if index > len(self):
            self.last = self._Node(value, _last=self.last)
        else:
            where = self.__get_node(index)
            _last = where._last
            new_node = self._Node(value, _next=where, _last=_last)
            if _last:
                _last._next = new_node
            else:
                self.start = new_node

            where._last = new_node
```

### Example

```
ll = LinkedList(range(1, 5))
print(*ll)

print(*reversed(ll))

ll.insert(2, 'foo')
print(*ll)
```

### Output

```
1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1
1 2 foo 3 4
```